# How to query Win32_Printer for installed remote printer? (Invalid Query)

Tags: c#, .net, wmi-query

I´m getting Invalid Query error when trying to get locally installed remote printer info from Win32_Printer.

```
string query = "SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name = '\\\\Server\\PrinterName'";

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
SelectQuery objQuery = new SelectQuery(query);
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, objQuery))
using (ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get())
{
   foreach (ManagementObject printer in coll)
   {
      foreach (PropertyData property in printer.Properties)
         {
            result.Add(property.Name, property.Value);
         }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the name
*'\\\\Server\\PrinterName'*
from
System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.

If I change the query to

```
"SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '%PrinterName'"
```

it works but how can I query on the full name?

Comment: Have you tried without the escaped path, i.e. `\\Server\PrinterName`?

Comment: @stuartd get Unrecognized escape sequence as expected...

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry, being dumb.

Comment: @stuartd Sorry if that came out harsh, was not my intention. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: ``\`` is an escape character in C# as well as WMI. Either double up the backslashes once more, or (more sanely) use ``@`` to bypass the C# escaping: `string query = @"SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name = '\\\\Server\\PrinterName'";`

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comment from @JeroenMostert, the '\' character is an escape character in both c# and wmi so the solution is to double them.